# Access allure reports while test is running

Tags: java, jenkins, allure

We're using TestNG+Allure reports for our java testing infrastructure. The test might take up to 4 hours to run. We want to see the reports of tests that are already done in the suite.

Can I see a report in between? How can one implement it?

I'm using Jenkins but I believe the solution might be different (since Jenkins supports publishing the reports only as a post-build action).

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
allure serve /home/path/to/project/target/surefire-reports/
```

Based on Allure document: it generates a report in temporary folder from the data found in the provided path and then creates a local Jetty server instance, serves generated report and opens it in the default browser.